# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'RM' not found

Tags: r, excel, csv

I'm Trying to do a simple linear regresion by calling a .CSV file where i have 14 different variables...which were first in a Excel file.
In Excel i named the variables by just putting a name above the data, but i don't really believe that means that that names the whole column by that variable.
(Of course i first call the .CSV file from R:

```
> datos<-read.table("datos3.csv",header=T,sep=";",dec=",")
```

So that must be why when i call them by name in R like:

```
 regresion<-lm(RM~MEDV) 
 R says: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'RM' not found
```

The thing i find strange is that when i change the order of the variables (say MEDV~RM) i get the same error but saying that MEDV was not found this time. Is it because is the first thing it reads and detects?

Is there a way from Excel or R that i can name the variables for me to call them without errors or is the problem anywhere else?

UPDATED CODE

```
 rm(list=ls())
 datos<-read.table("datos3.CSV",header=T,sep=";",dec=",")
 View(datos)
 regresion<-lm(MEDV,RM,data=datos)
```

After this i get

```
  Error in stats::model.frame(formula = MEDV, data = datos, subset = RM,  : 
  object 'MEDV' not found
```

Comment: You are missing a `data=datos` argument in `lm`. Otherwise, `lm` cannot find the variables.

Comment: You have to tell `lm()` where to find the `RM` and `MEDV` variables. Try ` regresion<-lm(RM~MEDV, data = datos)`.

Comment: Its strange because it should work but i get the same error but with an extra now:
Error in stats::model.frame(formula = MEDV, data = datos, subset = RM,  : 
  object 'MEDV' not found

Comment: re your coment; thats doesnt look like a correct formula or use of subset . Can you share your updated lm code that is throwing the above error please. (Also remember that R is case-sensitive)

Comment: @user20650 i updated what i typed in R above. I'm still confused why R doesn't find the variables.

Comment: your formula is wrong. `lm(MEDV ~ RM, data = datos)`

Comment: i'm still getting `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'MEDV' not found` when i write that correction.

Comment: can you post `str(datos)` please?  Are you sure you got the variable names right?

Comment: `str(datos) 
 $ X1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13.14...: Factor w/ 507 levels "0.00632,18,2.31,0,0.538,6.575,65.2,4.09,1,296,15.3,396.9,4.98,24,,,",..: 507 1 25 24 34 112 29 138 199 235 ...`  I thought it could be that the variables didn't follow the same name as in Excel. (since im new to R i dont know what im reading here)

Comment: ugh is your data a `csv` (comma separated)? Then you probably dont want a `';'` (semi-colon)  separator. If so, try reading in with `read.csv`, which has easier default settings.

Comment: But from your `str` it does look like your data is not getting read in correctly. After reading in data, I find it useful to examine a few things before beginning analysis... have a look at `str(datos)` as Ben suggested, also `head(datos)` and `tail(datos)`, and perhaps `summary(datos)`. These give an indication that the format and class of the variables are what you expect.

Comment: @user20650 yes, after typing summary(datos) i get that the data is comma separated, instead of a ';' separator should i put a comma? or anything else?

Comment: okay, so the first thing is to read in your data correctly. Try `datos <- read.csv("datos3.csv", dec=",")` and then have a look at it.

Comment: Much better, now are the real variable names in the upper tabs? if so the real ones are X1, X2,...X14. When i call them by that i get:
`regresion<-lm(X14 ~ X6, data = datos)
Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
`

Comment: okay, so your data is still not read in correctly - you are expecting numeric but they are getting read in as character (and then coerced to factor). After using read.csv, you need to examine the data (as indicated in previous comments, at least, use `str(datos)`). You need to get the variable formats sorted before you begin any analysis. Also does your csv file have headers - if so, the default for read.csv is header=TRUE, so it is strange that they are not getting read in?

Comment: I don't really understand what im reading here [link]http://i.imgur.com/f2025dR.jpg

Comment: ok, thanks. Your first row of your data are the column names of your csv data, which is not what you want, so it is still not read in correctly. As the names are included as data (rather than as headers), you are mixing characters and numeric, hence why the format is getting messed up.

Comment: What code did you use to read in ... the `read.csv` above. Do you have a blank line before your column names / data begins in your raw csv? If so, try `datos <- read.csv("datos3.csv", dec=",", skip=1)`

Comment: @user20650 So i deleted the first row (the one with names) by modifying de excel file but i'm still getting factor values, and the same error as before. Why would now that be?

Comment: Something as small as a misplaced comma in a column would coerce the column to character / factor. Without actually, looking at the raw data, i dont know what else to suggest. If you can share it / upload it online somewhere (dropbox?) without requiring a password, ill have a look.

Comment: Sure thing, thank you in advance for all the help
[link]https://www.dropbox.com/sh/319tnpyydzxxan2/AACmW5ynlMOZkJ2hpjogH7Q1a?dl=0[/link]

Comment: It is the `dec` argument thats messing things. just use `datos <- read.csv("datos3.csv")` . Note this will most likely work with your original csv with the headers as well. (why were you using dec - it appears as if all the decimals are already coded with a point)

Comment: Finally, can't believe it took this long to fix this. I'm really thankful, would you write an "Answer" instead if a comment so i can mark it? Thank you very much

Comment: Got there in the end... you're very welcome. Im a wee bit surprised how a mis-used dec argument could mess things up. Please fell free to write it up (and you might find it useful), perhaps working through the comments explaining why things didnt work.

Comment: btw.. ikn ow it is much more fun ust to get stuck into the data, but i think you'd find it useful to have a read of some of the docs... https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html is a good place to start. cheers

Comment: All right, i'll write the answer up when i finish my work with this data. And again thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the problem is that since i was using first an excel file for my data, i had the variables named included in the first row, so when passing it to .CSV format and trying to read it in R, it transformed those characters into data as factors. So when trying to do a regresion it did not have only number values.

After that it was the "dec"argument in the read.csv causing trouble and printing the same error. So after removing that and typing:

```
datos <- read.csv("datos3.csv")
```

I had no trouble making the regresion and could analyze the data i wanted.
(special thanks to @user20650 for helping me out)